# More Efficient Way To Wait/Listen for a Process

Tags: vb.net, pdf, process

I have a tool that I have been using but it is hit or miss. It uses sendkeys to open a pdf from another application. I then check to see if the pdf opened, close that pdf by killing the process, then use sendkeys again to go to the next document. However, I have found that if there is any lag time between network and/or filesize, the program doesn't detect the process and the program stops functioning. Is there a better way to listen to a process?

```
Sub ProcessPDF()
        Dim z As Integer = Next1
        AppActivate("Hyperspace")
        For i = 1 To z          
            SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}")
            p = Process.GetProcessesByName("Acrobat")
            If p.Count > 0 Then
                p(0).CloseMainWindow()      
                SendKeys.SendWait("{LEFT}")
                SendKeys.SendWait("^Q")
                SendKeys.SendWait("{DOWN}")
            Else
                label2.Text = "An error has occurred! Please try again."
                MsgBox("An error has occurred! Please try again.")
            End If
            Next1 = Next1 - 1
            label2.Text = Next1 & " PDFs Left!"
        Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Way 1:

```
wait:
For Each p In Process.GetProcesses
    If p.ProcessName = ("Acrobat") Then
         Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
         GoTo wait
    End If
Next
```

Way2:

```
Private Function Run(ByVal process As String, ByVal parameters As String) As String
                Dim psi As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo(process)
                psi.Arguments = "your commands"
                psi.RedirectStandardError = True
                psi.UseShellExecute = False
                Dim output As String = String.Empty
                Dim proc As Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi)
                proc.WaitForExit()
                Dim outputStream As StreamReader = proc.StandardError
                output = outputStream.ReadToEnd
                proc.Close()
                Return output
End Function
```

Force Kill:

```
waitkill:
        For Each p In Process.GetProcesses
            If p.ProcessName = ("Acrobat") Then
                p.Kill()
                GoTo waitkill
            End If
        Next
```